# Displaying json data on leaflet map

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet, markers

I would like to create an web app which is going to show amount of available spots and bikes on a station.

I have an open API with is providing a real-time data. - [API HERE](https://oslobysykkel.no/en/open-data/realtime)

I'm using [Leaflet Maps](http://www.leafletjs.com) for map.

I currently have made 2 scripts.

**leafletmap.js**

This script is showing a map with center location of Oslo, Norway.

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([59.9139, 10.7522], 13); // This line is lan,lat for location, "13" is a zoom parameter.

    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1
    }).addTo(mymap);

    

    L.circle([59.9139, 10.7522], 60, { // This is what I want to use as bike station 
location
        color: 'blue',
        fillColor: 'blue',
        fillOpacity: 0.5
    }).addTo(mymap).bindPopup("I am a circle.");
```

Here is a code for receiving data from API.

**api.js**

```
const GbfsClient = require('gbfs-client');
const gbfsClient = new GbfsClient('https://gbfs.urbansharing.com/oslobysykkel.no/');

gbfsClient.stationInfo()
    .then(osloStatus => console.log(osloStatus));
```

I want to display a Bike station locations on my map.

This end-point is the one that I need to use - https://gbfs.urbansharing.com/oslobysykkel.no/station_information.json

**Goal**: Change this hard-scripted part of the code >

```
L.circle([*lat and lon to be inserted here*], 60, {
        color: 'blue',
        fillColor: 'blue',
        fillOpacity: 0.5
    }).addTo(mymap).bindPopup("**Name of bike station here.**");
```

To be changed with a response of endpoint > Lat, lan, name of bike station.

JSON response >

```
{
  "last_updated": 1553592653,
  "data": {
    "stations": [
      {  
        "station_id":"627",
        "name":"Skøyen Stasjon",
        "address":"Skøyen Stasjon",
        "lat":59.9226729,
        "lon":10.6788129,
        "capacity":20
      },
      {  
        "station_id":"623",
        "name":"7 Juni Plassen",
        "address":"7 Juni Plassen",
        "lat":59.9150596,
        "lon":10.7312715,
        "capacity":15
      },
      {  
        "station_id":"610",
        "name":"Sotahjørnet",
        "address":"Sotahjørnet",
        "lat":59.9099822,
        "lon":10.7914482,
        "capacity":20
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**EDIT1**

I realise that I wrote a lot of text making a mess a little bit.
Shortly- I want to display a location of bike stations on my map( I have lat and lan location from API). How I can display it using API. There is 150+ locations and adding all of them by hand it's not a deal, also there is chance that something can be added/deleted in future.

For a marker of location I hard-scripted a red circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can display them using an API by simply fetching the data like below and then iterate over them and display markers with their popup info. Because you have hundreds of markers it will be good to use `preferCanvas: true` option to avoid possible bad browser performance while rendering the markers.

```
fetch("https://gbfs.urbansharing.com/oslobysykkel.no/station_information.json")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseData) => {
    console.log(responseData.data);
    const stations = responseData.data.stations;

    const layerGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);

    stations.forEach(({ lat, lon, name, address }) => {
      layerGroup.addLayer(
        L.marker([lat, lon], { icon }).bindPopup(
          `Name: ${name}, Address: ${address}`
        )
      );
    });

    map.fitBounds(layerGroup.getBounds());
  });
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/displaying-json-data-on-leaflet-map-ynkv8?file=/src/index.js:601-1144)

Comment: After trying to do the same with a demo I receive an error - Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "leaflet". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../". Any ideas what's wrong? I think it's something with imports

Comment: Probably you did not install leaflet. You can download the emo I provided and play around

Comment: I checked dependancies and I install it immediately. Still receive this error. I'm running live-server extension, cause before I was receiving CORS related error.

Comment: I even downloaded the whole leaflet as dir and make a path in a HTML head, still error remains. I'm using your demo.

Comment: I am not sure what is your issue because I don't know your machine's setup neither the config of the server you mentioned. This answer should work if everything is set up as expected. Please accept it and/or up vote it if it helped you.